# How does the "skip code" work in The Empty Hearse?

Tags: analysis, sherlock

In the first episode of season 3 of Sherlock named as "The Empty Hearse". We can see that Mary received a message from the John's kidnapper(s). Mary said it's a skip code and Sherlock told that the formula to decrypt is

> First word, then every third

The message after decryption was like

> **Save** souls Now!
>
> **John** or James **Watson!**
>
> **Saint** or Sinner?
>
> **James** or John?
>
> **The** more is **less**?

But according to Sherlock's theory how is it possible? As `Saint` is just after `Watson`. So what am I missing?

Also picture of the scenes

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about it, but i think both are 2 separate messages.

Comment: I guess the real question is, how did Mary 'the receptionist' immediately identify it as a skip code?! well spotted.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Yes I also thought about that question but asking here will give us some *opinion based* answer which is not welcome in SE sites. Maybe Mary was reading [John's blog](http://www.johnwatsonblog.co.uk/) and if you go through the story you will also get that sms was some sort of puzzle or maybe something else which will be reavealed later!

Comment: 'I guess the real question is, how did Mary 'the receptionist' immediately identify it as a skip code?!' **Watches Sherlock. Puts sunglasses on. Leans back in chair with hands behind his head.**

Comment: Okay, this may be a huge jump, but has anyone else thought of Moriarty? It was the first thing that popped into my mind. I mean, his real name is **James** Moriarty, after all. Idk, it could be the location but "James" can't get out of my head. Maybe I've seen too much Sherlock lately.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional the answer to your question is revealed on episode 3.

Comment: erm...yeah... that's what the comment is about? ;) I figured something was up with this last week....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you rewatch it, they are indeed two separate messages. They pop up on her screen separately.

> Save souls Now!
>
> John or James Watson!

then

> Saint or Sinner?
>
> James or John?
>
> The more is less?

Comment: I really thought someone would get it first while I fast-forwarded to find it as verification.

Comment: We @ Movies SE strive for correct answers than quick answers :P

Comment: Msgs to her came the way this answer is.. Actully each line is a new message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think grouping the messages is relevant. The pattern applies to each individual sentence.

Comment: The sentences are only three or four words each, so the order of the sentences is *very important*. "Save The Less James Saint John Watson" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The OP wanted to know why 'Saint' would follow 'Watson' and the accepted answer implied that 'Saint or Sinner' was the start of a second separate message (meaning it would use the first word) whereas in reality the 'First then every third' applies to each individual sentence. Therefore, trying to group the messages is irrelevant. See also Ronak Bhatt's answer.

Comment: Re: your edit. Just because I disagree with you, or you weren't clear enough in your statement makes me a "smartass?" **No need to be rude.** And if you notice, each of the two messages *does* following the every third word, even among the sentences. This is what confused the OP, and why my answer was accepted. I answered their question about a possible discrepancy. And *the groupings matter* as they *each* give a complete message. 1- Rescue, 2- Location.

Comment: Apologies for the rudeness. However, I also considered your ridicule a bit rude as well. Just state '_if sentence order is not important, the deciphered code would be jumbled_'. Then, if I don't clarify the answer, a downvote is justified. I'll delete the answer in a bit, since there seems to be such an outcry.

Comment: I didn't mean it as ridicule, *at all*, just as an example of how the message would not make sense out of order. That's the problem with text sometimes. It's sometimes hard to "read." Sorry you took it as such. And I didn't know a clarification would be coming. I thought you meant the order didn't matter. Period. No need to delete. Near as I can tell, the only outcry was me. Maybe I'm the only one who doesn't understand what you were trying to say. So be it. (Mainly, I just didn't like being called a "smartass" when I didn't think it was justified. Apology accepted. Downvote retracted.) Peace.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Very gracious. Thanks. I actually make a conscious effort not be rude on the other SE sites. My bad, really.